# Display list of objects in a data grid

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I'm new to C# and WPF, I want to display a list of user objects(PartnerID and PartnerName) and a checkbox asking whether to delete the Partner, in a datagrid. I have written the following code but only the column headers are displayed and the values are not displayed. i think its the problem with binding but i'm not able to trace it. can you plz help me..

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)        
{
    List<Partners> partners = new List<Partners>();
    DataAccess DA = new DataAccess();
    partners = DA.GetAllPartners();
    this.dataGrid1.DataContext = partners;
    this.dataGrid1.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Id", Binding new Binding("PartnerId") });
    this.dataGrid1.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = "Partner Name", Binding = new Binding("PartnerName") });
    this.dataGrid1.Columns.Add(new DataGridCheckBoxColumn
    {
        Header = "Delete?",
        Binding = new Binding(" ")
     });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you do this thing in XAML? code behind is complex and more error prone in situations like these

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the DataGrid's `ItemSource` property rather than its `DataContext`...

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = partners;
```

On an unrelated note but relevant for people new to WPF - check out the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) (Model-View-ViewModel) design pattern. It will help you organize this type of code in a much more maintainable fashion.

Comment: thank you.. this will dispaly the data in the list.. but i need a checkbox in the third column of every row.. how can i do that if i use ItemSource     property